# Keep "sudo" privileges for all the time a script is running?

Tags: sudo

I'd like my script to do the following:

```
sudo true # cache the password so we don't have to ask twice
git clone (...) # as normal user
cd repo
sudo docker build -t name .
sudo docker run  name
```

The thing is that "sudo docker build" might take so much that the user is asked for password more than once. Is there a way I could cache the credentials for a longer period of time than the default one?

Comment: Not from the script, I don't think, but you could recommend that users of it extend their timeouts.

Answer (score 0):

What about starting a shell with sudo, and running the commands inside that?

Something like:

`git clone repo
cd repo
sudo sh -c 'docker build -t name . && docker run name'`

Comment: This way Git  would also be ran as root and the user's SSH keys wouldn't be used.

Comment: Ya, so you'd put the git checkout before this. The OP says that it's docker build that might time out. I'll edit it to make that obvious.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if i understand the question correctly, but you might want to add the user to sudoers.

to do so:

```
visudo
```

and enter the following line where username needs to be replaced by the actual username.

```
username         ALL=(ALL)  NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Or if you don't want to allow sudo without password on all execuables you could use:

```
username         ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /path/to/executable
```

Comment: I would prefer to keep the password prompt.

Comment: Than you can try to change the timeout on sudo itself. Like they show here:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudoTimeout